# typeahead, bloodhound : remote works but not prefetch

Tags: typeahead, prefetch, bloodhound

I want to use prefetch and I can't have it working !
Here is my code :

```
function initAutocompletion() {
    $("input[data-autocomplete-prefetch-url]").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
    var urlPrefetch = $this.data("autocomplete-prefetch-url");
    var prefetch;

    pref = {
        url: urlPrefetch,
        filter: filter
    };

    var bloodHound = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 10,
        prefetch: pref
    });

    bloodHound.initialize();

    $this
        .typeahead('destroy')
        .typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: bloodHound.ttAdapter()
        });
    });
 }

function filter(list) {
    return $.map(list, function (v) { return { value: v.toString() }; });
}
```

It doesn't work.

If I use remote instead of prefetch it works !

```
    var bloodHound = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 10,
        remote: pref
    });
```

I can't anderstand.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Amazingly it worked this morning !
So it drove me to think it was about cache... And it was !
Adding clearPrefetchCache() before initializing bloodhound did the trick.

```
       bloodHound.clearPrefetchCache();
       bloodHound.initialize();
```

I think it didn't show any suggestions because it has cached an empty list.

Comment: Official example with prefetch didn't work for me without `clearPrefetchCache`. Adding `clearPrefetchCache` before `initialize` helped. Though it doesn't explain, what's going on.

Comment: Probably worth noting that this may not be a great idea for production depending on your app because if you clear the prefetch cache on every page load, you have to reload the data into the cache on every page load so you only get the advantage of the cache until you switch pages or reload the current page.  Probably a great idea for a development environment though.

Answer (score 10):

It's because typeahead already loaded your data from prefetch url and stored it in `localStorage`. At the time data is in `localStorage`, prefetch is not invoked.

Try change `cacheKey` prefetch option like below and reload the page. Prefetch will invoke because there is no data tied to the new cacheKey in `localStorage`.

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: {
    url: "stations.json",
    cacheKey: "change here!"
  }
});
```

You can also check local storage with chrome developer tools.

[image]

Try to delete local storage data and reload page. Prefetch will invoke.

To remove localStorage data before Bloodhound initialization makes its prefetch invoke at every initialization time.

```
localStorage.removeItem("YOUR CACHEKEY");

// Bloodhound initialization with YOUR CACHEKEY.
```

`clearPrefetchCache()` before `initialize()` is better, I think.

Comment: `.initialize(true)` also makes the cache clear each time it's called.

Comment: Great info, doesn't provide the solution though.

Comment: @Stuffix I don't think so.  In my testing environment, I have `.initialize(true)`.  If I remove `.clearPrefetchCache()` from before the initialize, the prefetches stop hitting my server.  From my experiments (version 0.11.1), if you want to clear the prefetch cache, you have to call `.clearPrefetchCache()` before `.initialize(true)`

Comment: @davew you probably right, I wrote this comment 3 years ago so things might have change since.  I didn't messed with typeahead since.

Answer (score 2):

I ran across your question while having issues getting `prefetch` to work even though `remote` was working fine.  I first worked through caching concerns (since it's been an issue before), but it still wasn't working.

Next I implemented `templates` in typeahead so I could get some feedback regarding what was happening when I clicked and typed in the field and nothing happened.  My `notFound` template was appearing.  This seemed odd since I could see prefetch hit the server. With debug output at the server I could also tell the server was generating the proper json response.

When inspecting the json though I noticed that it had no whitespace and my bloodhound `datumTokenizer` was configured as `Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace`.  This caused me to dig deeper into how the tokenizers are supposed to work.

I found this very helpful:
  https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/migration/0.10.0.md#tokenization-methods-must-be-provided

My issue was resolved after switching to:

```
datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
```

(where `.value` is the json property I want to search)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on tokenizers? [We don't understand why they'd differ for prefetch vs remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971010/typeahead-bloodhound-autocomplete-using-prefetch-remote-when-source-is-a-dict)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are trying to prefetch data earlier than urlPrefetch gets a value. Try to dump urlPrefetch to console and check that it has a valid url.