# Typeahead Bloodhound Autocomplete using prefetch + remote when source is a dict from Django

Tags: javascript, django, autocomplete, typeahead.js, bloodhound

[Bloodhound variable for Typeahead](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js) that's working nicely:

```js
var egDjangoVar = new Bloodhound({
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  remote: {
    url: '/ajax/eg/%QUERY.json', 
    wildcard: '%QUERY',
    filter: filterdata
  }
});
```

We added dict parsing function `filter: filterdata` because Django requires JSON to be sent as a dict for security:

```js
function filterdata(data){
      return $.map(data.results, function(results,index){
        return results.value;
      })
    }
```

All works beautifully. We now want [Prefetch functionality](https://typeahead.js.org/examples/#prefetch) and have added:

```js
prefetch: {
    url: '/ajax/prefetch.json',
    wildcard: '%QUERY',
    filter: filterdata
  },
```

This doesn't work, despite `'/ajax/prefetch.json'` serving expected dict. We think it may be due to `dataTokenizer` issues [discussed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43527447/4107349), but we don't understand why the tokenizer should differ between remote and prefetch sources, and the suggested `datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value)};` didn't work when adding it as an argument of `prefetch`.

We've found that `__/ajax/prefetch.json__data` in local storage is saved with dict keys matching values like `{"datums":{"Apple":"Apple","Banana":"Banana","Orange":"Orange"},"trie":{"i":[],"c":{}}}`, whereas the remote data directly viewed is like `{"results": [{"value": "Apple"}, {"value": "Banana"}, {"value": "Orange"}]}`. Is this unexpected?

I'm new to front end / JS, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: the `filter` function should return `results` instead of `results.value`.

`display:'value'` was also missing from the Typeahead initialization (where Bloodhound variable is given to `source`).